# how to pass a service role to my stack when using CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When using CloudFormation to deploy AWS resources you can assign a service role to the stack

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
  --stack-name ${STACK_NAME} \
  --template-body file://stack.yaml \
  --role-arn ${SERVICE_ROLE_ARN}
```

How can you do the same thing when using CDK? I see that the StackProps construct does not have a role-arn attribute.

Comment: In what language? Please edit your question in line with [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you for your advice; however, I don't think the language used to write the CDK code is relevant here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  -r, --role-arn            ARN of Role to use when invoking CloudFormation
```

as found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cli.html

however. Ermiya is correct in the comments to your answer, that anything beyond a deployment time role for deployment requires the language you are using - Its slightly, but importantly different in each one. Plus, there are many other factors in CDK deployment that are not part of the CloudFormation Create Stack options, such as AWS Environment (region and account number) and more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the answer is use cdk  deploy -r ${ROLE_ARN} I don't see how the language you use to write you CDK code is relevant.

Comment: It's only relevant If you're trying to do something far more involved.  Such as anything in CICD using a CodePipeline - if you aren't just doing a cdk deploy inside a codebuild then you have to be able to define/create the role with the pipeline stack and pass that role arn to the stack being deployed.